# GWTBootstrap3: DatePicker

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3, gwtbootstrap3

I derived my own DatePicker class from `org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.datepicker.client.ui.DatePicker`. (GWTBootstrap 0.9.3)

My DatePicker shows up on the far right side on the screen, on various vertical positions (at the top of the screen, in the middle, and on the far bottom)

I use `DatePickerPosition.AUTO`.

My problem is that datepickers which are located at the bottom of the screen still open up to the bottom and therefore are only in part visible. I would have expected that AUTO would decide whether to the top or  to the bottom is better. So a datepicker shown on the bottom of the screen would automatically popup to the top?

Any insights on this?

Comment: I tried this "hack" on the ShowEvent ... but setting the position in the Handler does not seem to work? this.addShowHandler(new ShowHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onShow(final ShowEvent showEvent) {
    if (getAbsoluteTop() > Window.getClientHeight()/2) {
     setPosition(DatePickerPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    } else {
     setPosition(DatePickerPosition.TOP_LEFT);
    }
   }

  });

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `DatePicker`: http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/apidocs/

Comment: take a look at this: http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#datePicker